# How Do I Submit My Form in Shadowbox?

Tags: html, forms, submit, shadowbox

I'm trying to use Shadowbox to upload image files. The Shadowbox opens fine with the form in the browser, but I'm unable to submit it. The server says its unable to complete my request. Here is my Shadowbox code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            Shadowbox.init({

            });

            function myTest() {

                Shadowbox.open({
                    content:    "http://mydomain.com/cgi-bin/photo.cgi,
                    player:     "iframe",
                    title:      "Image Upload",
                    height:     200,
                    width:      500
                });

            };

        </script>
```

I call the Shadowbox using a button:

```
<tr><td colspan="7"><input type="button" value="Upload Photo" onClick="myTest();"></td></tr>
```

My form code is here:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://mydomain.com/cgi-bin/photo.cgi?function=photo_upload_process" method="get" target="_parent">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 50px;"></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 175px;"><label>Load Image:</label></td>
            <td style="width: 275px;"><input class="photo_selector" type="file" name="photo" size="20"></td>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 20px;"></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 175px;"><label>Press Button to Upload:</td>
            <td style="width: 275px;"><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload"></td>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 20px;"></td></tr>

    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="function" value="upload_image">

</form>
```

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to upload a file using the "get" method for your form.

method="get" will try to send form data as query-string parameters.
This will not work for uploading a file.